# Setting default schema in postgresql (spring)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, heroku

On my own machine I modify `postgresql.conf`, but I don't think Heroku gives access to that file. Does anyone know any alternative methods to set the default schema?

Setting it on every connection seems kinda ugly.

Comment: If you *always* want to use that schema, you can make it the default schema by running `alter user set schema 'default_schema'`

Comment: thanks horse. should add as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create user in postgres db with same name as schema name. Login with this new user, it will
automatically point to schema with user.

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>
  <Resource name="jdbc/DatabaseName" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="acme" password="dbPasswd"
              url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mydb"
              driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
              initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
              maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              poolPreparedStatements="true"/>
</GlobalNamingResources/>
```

with this configuration, jndi lookup for resource "jdbc/DatabaseName" with return database connection pointing to schema name matching user "acme", ie acme.